Double Integral Simplification Question
I was reading Brauer and Nohel's ODEs book and came upon the following equality on page 110:
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{t} \int \limits_{0}^{s} g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d \tau ds = \int \limits_{0}^{t} \left( \int \limits_{\tau}^{t} ds \right) g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d\tau = \int \limits_{0}^{t} (t - \tau) g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d\tau
$$
At first I thought it was just a consequence of Fubini's Theorem, but upon closer look that is not the case. Fubini only gives:
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{t} \int \limits_{0}^{s} g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d \tau ds = \int \limits_{0}^{s} \int \limits_{0}^{t} g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) ds d\tau = \int \limits_{0}^{t} g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) \left( \int \limits_{0}^{t} ds \right) d\tau = \int \limits_{0}^{t} t g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d\tau
$$
Could someone please explain where the first series of equalities came from?

You are right. It is Fubini with proper integral limits. I used to be confused as well.
We are evaluating the double integral that is taken over the domain $(\tau,s)$.
$$I=\int \limits_{0}^{t} \int \limits_{0}^{s} g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d \tau ds$$
which integrates firstly on $\tau\in[0,s]$ and then on $s\in[0,t]$, which implicitly means ${0\le\tau\le s\le t}$.
By Fubini's theorem, it is possible to change the integration order and note that $\tau\le s\le t$, therefore, you can write
$$I=\int \limits_{0}^{t} \left( \int \limits_{\tau}^{t} ds \right) g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d\tau=\int \limits_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)g(\tau, \phi(\tau)) d\tau.$$

Ah, so that's what it was. Thank you so much!

You are mostly welcome!
